# Is there a way to compare incidences of 2 diseases in the same cohort?

Tags: incidence-rate-ratio

I would like to compare incidences of 2 diseases in the same cohort for the past 10 years.
Eg. I want to see whether there's an association between incidence of heart disease and incidence of influenza in the same cohort of people for the past 10 years. 
Is this doable? What statistical method should I use? Thank you

Comment: Make a $2 \times 2$ table with rows Flu/NoFlu and columns HD/NoHD. Use Fisher's Exact test.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have table:

```
        ND  noHD
Flu     10    5
noFlu    5   10
```

Perhaps suggestive of association, but not significant.
Not enough data.

```
TBL = rbind(c(10,5), c(5,10))
fi        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.1431
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.7054268 23.9214257
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  3.805039
```

However, if you have table:

```
        ND   noHD
Flu     102    53
noFlu    49   105
```

Roughly the same *proportions* as in the former example,
but with about ten times the number of subjects. Highly
significant.

```
TBL2 = rbind(c(102,53), c(49,105))
fisher.test(TBL2, alt="two")

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL2
p-value = 2.445e-09
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.498319 6.820386
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  4.103514
```